# auto reconnect VPN on waking up

Tags: linux-mint, sleep

When I wake up my computer, the internet automatically reconnects, however the VPN does not. 
Is it possible to make it automatically reconnect (using the network manager on KDE, or at least in a way that the network manager is aware if it being connected via VPN) ?

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution on Ubuntu forums (for example, [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1316314.html)):

1. Start a text editor with elevated privileges. For example, enter at the command prompt:

   ```
   gksudo gedit
   ```

   You need your editor running with elevated privileges because you will be saving a file in a folder that you can't make changes to with a "normal" access level.
2. Create a file called `autovpn` and save it in the directory `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`.  In this `autovpn` file, place the following code:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python

   import sys
   import os
   import dbus
   import gobject
   from  dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

   # The uuid of the VPN connection to activate
   VPN_CONNECTION_UUID = "FILL IN YOUR OWN"

   # The uuid of the connection that needs to be active to start the VPN connection
   ACTIVE_CONNECTION_UUID = "FILL IN YOUR OWN"

   # some service, path and interface constants
   NM_DBUS_SERVICE                   = "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
   NM_DBUS_PATH                      = "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager"
   NM_DBUS_INTERFACE                 = "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
   NM_DBUS_IFACE_CONNECTION_ACTIVE   =   "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active"
   NM_DBUS_SERVICE_SYSTEM_SETTINGS   = "org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerSystemSettings"
   NM_DBUS_SERVICE_USER_SETTINGS     = "org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerUserSettings"
   NM_DBUS_IFACE_SETTINGS            = "org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerSettings"
   NM_DBUS_PATH_SETTINGS             = "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManagerSettings"
   NM_DBUS_IFACE_SETTINGS_CONNECTION = "org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerSettings.Connection"

   DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

   nm_dbus_settings_services = (NM_DBUS_SERVICE_SYSTEM_SETTINGS,    NM_DBUS_SERVICE_USER_SETTINGS)

   def get_connections(bus, service):
   proxy = bus.get_object(service, NM_DBUS_PATH_SETTINGS)
   iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, dbus_interface=NM_DBUS_IFACE_SETTINGS)
   return iface.ListConnections()

   def get_connection_by_uuid(bus, uuid):
     for service in nm_dbus_settings_services:
      for c in get_connections(bus, service):
        proxy = bus.get_object(service, c)
        iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, dbus_interface = NM_DBUS_IFACE_SETTINGS_CONNECTION)
        settings = iface.GetSettings()
          if settings['connection']['uuid'] == uuid:
            return (c, service)
       return None

     def list_uuids(bus):
     for service in nm_dbus_settings_services:
      for c in get_connections(bus, service):
   proxy = bus.get_object(service, c)
   iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, dbus_interface=NM_DBUS_IFACE_SETTINGS_CONNECTION)
   settings = iface.GetSettings()
   conn = settings['connection']
   print " %s: %s - %s (%s)" % (service, conn['uuid'], conn['id'], conn['type'])

        def get_active_connection_path(bus, uuid):
        proxy = bus.get_object(NM_DBUS_SERVICE, NM_DBUS_PATH)
        iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        active_connections = iface.Get(NM_DBUS_INTERFACE, 'ActiveConnections')
        connection_and_service = get_connection_by_uuid(bus, uuid)
       if connection_and_service == None:
        return None
       for a in active_connections:
       proxy = bus.get_object(NM_DBUS_SERVICE, a)
       iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
       path = iface.Get(NM_DBUS_IFACE_CONNECTION_ACTIVE, 'Connection')
       service = iface.Get(NM_DBUS_IFACE_CONNECTION_ACTIVE, 'ServiceName')
       if service != connection_and_service[1]:
       continue
       proxy = bus.get_object(connection_and_service[1], path)
       iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, dbus_interface=NM_DBUS_IFACE_SETTINGS_CONNECTION)
       settings = iface.GetSettings()
       if settings['connection']['uuid'] == uuid:
       return a
       return None

      def activate_connection(bus, vpn_connection, active_connection):
      def reply_handler(opath):
      print "<<SUCCESS>>"
      sys.exit(0)
      def error_handler(*args):
      print "<<FAILURE>>"
      sys.exit(1)
      proxy = bus.get_object(NM_DBUS_SERVICE, NM_DBUS_PATH)
      iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, dbus_interface=NM_DBUS_INTERFACE)
      iface.ActivateConnection(NM_DBUS_SERVICE_USER_SETTINGS,
                      vpn_connection[0],
                      dbus.ObjectPath("/"), 
                      active_connection,
                      reply_handler=reply_handler,
                      error_handler=error_handler)

       bus = dbus.SystemBus()

       #print "connections:"
       #list_uuids(bus)

       if len(VPN_CONNECTION_UUID) < 1 or len(ACTIVE_CONNECTION_UUID) < 1:
       print "you need to set the uuids"
       sys.exit(0)

       vpn_connection = get_connection_by_uuid(bus, VPN_CONNECTION_UUID)
       if not vpn_connection:
        print "Configured VPN connection is not known to NM, check VPN_CONNECTION_UUID."
       sys.exit(1)

       active_connection = get_connection_by_uuid(bus, ACTIVE_CONNECTION_UUID)
       if not active_connection:
        print "Configured active connection is not known to NM, check ACTIVE_CONNECTION_UUID."
        sys.exit(1)

       if get_active_connection_path(bus, VPN_CONNECTION_UUID) != None:
       print "VPN connection already activated"
       sys.exit(0)

       active_connection_path = get_active_connection_path(bus, ACTIVE_CONNECTION_UUID)
       if not active_connection_path:
       print "The required connection isn't active at the moment"
       sys.exit(0)

       print "connecting...." # to:\n  '%s'\nwith active connection:\n  '%s'" % (vpn_connection, active_connection)

       activate_connection(bus, vpn_connection, active_connection_path)

       loop = gobject.MainLoop()
       loop.run()
   ```
3. Go to the command prompt. Run the following command:

   ```
     nmcli con status
   ```

   Make note of the UUID values given, e.g., copy & paste them into a text file.
4. Back to the `autovpn` script: Fill in UUIDs for both the VPN connection you want to use, and the connection that has to be active before you can connect to VPN.

   For most users, the second one is your default network connection, usually a wired Ethernet connection.

   Note that the UUID values will be unique to your system. They shouldn't change from login to login, however, or this script wouldn't work. For your reference, here's what I see:

   ```
   $ nmcli con status
   NAME                      UUID                                   DEVICES    DEFAULT  VPN
   Wired connection 1        e9908d28-ffec-41cd-babb-c0cefb38ae6a   eth0       yes      no
   VPN Connection            699f17f2-0ab0-4d1d-94d3-24136ef81603   --         no       yes
   ```
5. Save the  `autovpn` file.
6. Log out and log back in or reboot. Your VPN connection should activate as soon as your regular network connection is on.

   Next step: implement the script to automatically detect whether VPN is still connected, and re-connect if not.

Hope this is of some help to you.

Comment: Does this help you Asaf ? If not leave a comment telling us why it does  not.